# Xtext and update project created by wizard

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext

Create a new DSL with Xtext a project with the prefix repository.

- Does this project create an update site for the plug-in?
- If it is the case must the project be configure and how is it deployed?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

Yes it creates a repo.
No there is no config needed unless you want to change contents. Then update category.xml

There is no deployment. You can e.g. upload the (unpacked) zip on a webserver or send it to your users via a file server 
(Could you give some more hints why you are asking)

Comment: I have no idea what is the best method to distribute a plugin create by Xtext, the people that will use the plugin is a small group.

Comment: I'd simply upload the unpacked zip to a local webserver

Comment: Hoe do you create the zip file? Which project should I include?

Comment: The wizard has an option to create a repo